# Simulating a discrete time stochastic process

Tags: simulation, random-process

I would like to simulate and plot many paths of a discrete random variable $\tau_{t}$ that follows the following process:

1. with probability $\tau_{t-1}$, $\tau_{t}$ is either $0.6$ with probability $x$ or $0.4$ with probability $1-x$. Then, $\tau_{t+1}$ is drawn according to the process.
2. with probability $1-\tau_{t-1}$, $\tau_{t}=\tau_{t-1}$. Then, $\tau_{t+1}$ is also equal to $\tau_{t}$ with probability $y$, or it is drawn according to point 1 of the described process with probability $1-y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [`RandomChoice`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomChoice.html) and [`NestList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html). Since $\tau_{t+1}$ may depend not only on $\tau_t$ but also on $\tau_{t-1}$, I keep an additional flag named `branch` which indicates whether $\tau_{t}$ was set to $\tau_{t-1}$ so that $\tau_{t+1}$ should be set according to different rules.

```
simulateτ[x_, y_, τ0_, steps_] := Module[{nextτ},
  nextτ[{τ_, branch_}] := If[branch == 0,
    RandomChoice[
     {τ, 1 - τ} -> {
       RandomChoice[{x, 1 - x} -> {{0.6, 0}, {0.4, 0}}],
       {τ, 1}
       }
     ],
    RandomChoice[
     {y, 1 - y} -> {
       {τ, 0},
       nextτ[{τ, 0}]
       }
     ]];
  First /@ NestList[nextτ, {τ0, 0}, steps]
  ]
```

Plotting is challenging because it is a discrete-state process. Here is an example for 100 trajectories with 200 steps each for $x=0.2, y=0.8, \tau_0 = 0.1$

```
ListPlot[Table[simulateτ[0.2, 0.8, 0.1, 200], 100], 
 Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.05, Gray]]
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks really a lot! Just a small follow-up: suppose that, when I leave branch 1, I want the first tau determined according to the x 1-x draw, and then the following according to the full process (including the tau / 1-tau draw). Should I add another branch?

Comment: @Federico, I don't really follow what you are trying to ask. Can you please write your question more precisely (or refer to the steps in your original post)?

Comment: sure, sorry for the lack of clarity. I have in mind something like this. During the "ordinary process", my random variable is 0.4 with probability x and 0.6 with probability 1-x. However, at the beginning of every period of the ordinary process, the variable may jump to a "slow process", where it remains constant, with probability $\tau_{t-1}$. When in the slow process, the variable can go back to the "ordinary process" with probability y. Does it make sense?

Comment: What you describe – and also your initial question – could very well be described also by a Markov chain (see [`DiscreteMarkovProcess`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteMarkovProcess.html)) with 6 states as I [schematically draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn1Ea.png) (I've just noticed there are some missing connections going from the slow back to the ordinary process, but you get the point). You can also adapt my code in a way that the `branch` flag denotes whether you are in the "ordinary" or "slow" process.